# Quick scroll in UITableView with sectionForSectionIndexTitle

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to allow scrolling through my `UITableView` by tapping the `sectionIndexTitles` on the side of the `UITableView`. So far my solution was as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSIndexPath *matchingIndexPathForTitle = [self matchingIndexPathForSectionIndexTitle:title];
    if (matchingIndexPathForTitle) {
        [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:matchingIndexPathForTitle
                         atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }
    return 1;
}
```

But it seems like **since iOS9 it always scrolls to the top of the `UITableView`**

I can guarantee that the `matchingIndexPathForTitle` is correct (e.g. section 1, row 22) and also changing to `animated:NO` doesn't make a difference.

Do you

1. have an explanation for this weird behavior? or
2. have any suggestion on how to implement the quick scrolling for iOS 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `sectionForSectionIndexTitle` is responsible for scrolling to the right section, not a cell, returning a valid section index number in this method will cancel all custom scrolling events.

For scrolling to a cell, the scrolling to the section has to be prevented. This can be done by returning an invalid section index e.g. -1

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSIndexPath *matchingIndexPathForTitle = [self matchingIndexPathForSectionIndexTitle:title];
    if (matchingIndexPathForTitle) {
        [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:matchingIndexPathForTitle
                         atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }
    return -1; // this will do the trick and not scroll to any section
}
```